# Route showing as a straight line and not along any road in OSM map

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have created an App using OSM map. The app is working fine, but the route from my current location to the destination is showing up as a straight line and not through any roads.

**The method I am using**:

```
public void addRouteOverlay(GeoPoint startPoint, GeoPoint endPoint) {
            // road manager
            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();

            // start and end points
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
            waypoints.add(startPoint);
            // GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9);
            waypoints.add(endPoint);
            // roadManager.addRequestOption("routeType=bicycle");
            // retreive the road between those points
            Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
            if (road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK){
                  Log.d("Road Status", ""+road.mStatus);
                }
            // Polyline with the route shape
            org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager
                    .buildRoadOverlay(road, this);
            // Polyline to the overlays of your map
            mapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
            // Refresh the map
            mapView.invalidate();
```

**The way I am calling the method**:

```
//to display route between current location and destination
                addRouteOverlay(new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude()), new GeoPoint(22.566039700000000000,
                                88.349356700000040000));
```

**What should I do get the desired route between my location and destination?**

Comment: Did you check `road.mStatus` or the log? Is `road` an actual route consisting of more than your two points?

Comment: I am getting Road Status(14367): 2

Comment: And my other question? Can you see the full request to OSRM in your log? Try to execute it in your browser.

Comment: No I can not see the full request. How do I check that?

Comment: when I use this: if (road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK){
      Log.d("Error", ""+road.mStatus);
    } I am getting an error in the logcat: 04-29 17:12:19.348: E/BONUSPACK(3529): OSRMRoadManager::getRoad: request failed.
04-29 17:12:19.348: D/Road Status(3529): 2

Comment: Then please try to create a manual request on [project-osrm.org](http://project-osrm.org) using *the same coordinates* and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Yes, it is showing a route